# Is there a naming convention to avoid GraphQL name collisions when you have same concepts in Query and Mutation?

Tags: graphql, naming-conventions, naming

I have the following Schema:

```
type ProviderDetails{ ... }

type CustomerDetails{ ... }

type Provider{
 details: ProviderDetails!
}

type Customer{
 details: CustomerDetails!
}

input CustomerModReq{...}

type CustomerModResp{...}

type CustomerM{
 modifyDetails(update:CustomerModReq):CustomerModResp!
}

input ProviderModReq{...}
type ProviderModResp{...}
type ProviderM{
 modifyDetails(update:ProviderModReq):ProviderModResp!
}

type Query{
 provider(id: String): Provider!
 customer(id:String): Customer!
}

type Mutation{
 provider(id:String): ProviderM!
 customer(id:String): CustomerM!
}
```

I'm just not sure that `M` as suffix is really idiomatic. What is the idiomatic way to deal with that naming problem?

Answer (score 2):

While attempting to namespace your mutations this way doesn't break the spec, it does run contrary to established conventions period so you're not going to find a *convention* around naming your superfluous types. The *conventional* way is to name your Mutation fields after whatever actions they represent:

```
type Mutation {
  modifyCustomer
  modifyProvider
}
```

When a schema is likely to include dozens or hundreds fields, it's also common to see naming like this:

```
type Mutation {
  customerAdd
  customerModify
  providerAdd
  providerModify
}
```

Namespacing mutations using separate types is generally inadvisable because it unnecessarily complicates both your backend code and your client code. For example, as a client, if I want to batch my mutation calls and take advantage of the fact that root level fields are resolved sequentially, I have to know to not only use aliases, but also know I have to alias the root fields to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: >"root level fields are resolved in parallel"
Is this true? If so, it makes a lot of sense what you're saying. Could you point to the documentation that says so?

Comment: Sorry, typo, missed a "not" in there. All "sibling" fields are resolved in parallel, *except* root level mutation fields, which are resolved sequentially. See [this section of the spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Normal-and-Serial-Execution).